# SSL causing 'Network Error' in React Native Expo project with Axios - how to ignore SSL for development?

Tags: react-native, ssl, axios, expo

I am working on a React Native Expo project.

`react-native`: 0.71.7
`expo`: 48.0.15
`Axios`: 1.4.0

When I request the server I get a "Network Error". I think it is because of SSL. How can I bypass or ignore SSL for development? I can not change anything on the backend, so the solution should be on the front end.

I tried to downgrade `Axios`, but it didn't work.
By the way, the protocol of API I am using is `https`

This is where I use axios.

```js
const authApi = axios.create({
  baseURL: BASE_URL,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  Accept: '*/*'
  }
})
export const signin = async (data) => await authApi.post(URL, data)
```